# Why do we use a different value of Quality Factor for different resonance and non-resonance circuits?

Tags: electric-current, resonance, phase-diagram

In my school , I was taught that **Quality Factor(Q.F) = reciprocal of Power Factor(P.F) = impeadance / resistance** .

But, while solving problems of resonance circuits I found that **Q.F = reactance / resistance**. I get ***1 as Q.F. if I try to use reciprocal of P.F*** (which of course is not my answer).

So, Can anyone please tell me why is this happening? and is it necessary that whenever we have 0 deg phase between current and voltage (like in resonance circuits), we have to use reactance / resistance. Otherwise impeadance / resistance.

P.S. I have attached a photo that shows two different values of QF when I try to solve by two different formulas.

Thanks in Advance!
[image]

Comment: I have never seen the quality factor being defined as the inverse of the power factor $\text{cos} \phi$. The ones in the picture are the correct ones for a series RLC circuit.